# Writing Specific CSV Rows to a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am using the csv library to read specific rows from several files I have. The problem I am having is saving those rows into a dataframe. I am getting an indexing error that I can't solve.

The current version of the code finds the column names (which is on the third row) and then starts finding the data I need (which starts on the sixth row and continues until it hits a blank row). Finding the column names works fine, but when I try to append the data to it, I get the error:
"InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
    i=0
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    with open('C:/Users/sword/Anaconda3/envs/exceltest/RF_SubjP02_Free_STATIC_TR01.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in csvreader:
           if csvreader.line_num == 3:  #this is for the column names
               print(row)
               df = pd.DataFrame(columns = row)
               df.columns = row
           if csvreader.line_num >= 6:  #this is for the data
               if row: #checks for blank row
                   if i<10: #just printing the top ten rows for debugging purposes, theres thousands I need
                       print(i)
                       i+=1
                       df.append(row)  #this is where I get the indexing error
               else: # breaks out of loop if
                   break
    print(df) #for double checking if it worked
```

EDIT:
A sample of the data is here:

```
Devices

1680

Column Name 1,Column Name 2,Column Name 3,Column Name 4,Column Name 5,Column Name 6,Column Name 7,Column Name 8,Column Name 9,Column Name 10,Column Name 11,Column Name 12,Column Name 13,Column Name 14,Column Name 15,Column Name 16,Column Name 17,Column Name 18,Column Name 19,Column Name 20,Column Name 21

Frame,Sub Frame,Sync,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,FS,FS

,,,V,V,V,V,V,V,V,V,V,V,V,V,V,V,V,V,V,V
1,0,0,1.28178e-005,-5.21866e-005,8.24e-006,1.19022e-005,1.00711e-005,3.02133e-005,2.83822e-005,0,6.40889e-006,-6.1037e-007,2.83822e-005,-6.40889e-006,2.65511e-005,1.46489e-005,1.73956e-005,1.09867e-005,0,0

1,1,0,9.82043e-006,-4.40121e-005,8.78497e-006,1.02673e-005,1.1706e-005,3.15758e-005,2.62023e-005,5.44972e-006,8.0438e-006,-1.06924e-005,2.91997e-005,-8.0438e-006,2.73686e-005,1.51939e-005,1.73956e-005,1.04417e-005,0,0

1,2,0,1.40167e-005,-3.27202e-005,1.00493e-005,1.22292e-005,1.33409e-005,3.55758e-005,2.57009e-005,6.58328e-006,9.67872e-006,-1.5499e-005,2.95376e-005,-8.47978e-006,2.98645e-005,1.47797e-005,1.42783e-005,9.89672e-006,0,0

1,3,0,1.83656e-005,-2.59735e-005,1.01692e-005,1.46816e-005,1.45617e-005,3.74506e-005,2.56355e-005,3.19357e-006,4.47972e-006,-1.95863e-005,2.93959e-005,-7.92392e-006,3.13469e-005,1.46489e-005,1.38423e-005,9.14466e-006,0,0

1,4,0,1.84419e-005,-2.20169e-005,8.5016e-006,1.52157e-005,1.46053e-005,3.87149e-005,2.44148e-005,6.53978e-007,-4.27252e-006,-1.96627e-005,2.87746e-005,-8.1528e-006,3.05185e-005,1.39513e-005,1.59568e-005,9.37354e-006,0,0

1,5,0,1.5837e-005,-1.80387e-005,7.46613e-006,1.39622e-005,1.40603e-005,4.07858e-005,2.10905e-005,0,-8.4253e-006,-1.45073e-005,2.88073e-005,-9.25364e-006,2.83277e-005,1.21529e-005,1.69705e-005,9.48254e-006,0,0

1,6,0,1.39295e-005,-1.44963e-005,7.52064e-006,1.24908e-005,1.42783e-005,4.23117e-005,1.63493e-005,0,-4.77405e-006,-9.22096e-006,2.98427e-005,-1.00711e-005,2.60933e-005,1.02455e-005,1.5935e-005,7.84765e-006,0,0
```

I want the output to be a dataframe with row 3 as the column names and row 6 until a blank row as the data filling the columns.

For example:

```
    In[1]: csv file above
    Out[1]: [column Name 1]   [Column Name 2] ...
            [Data 1 in Row 6] [Data 2 in Row 6] ...
            [Data 1 in Row 7] [Data 2 in Row 7] ...
            [Data 1 in Row 8] [Data 2 in Row 8] ...
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected output?

Comment: Yes, I have added it

Comment: I think sample data in text, if use pictures I cannot copy data. Also what is expected output?

Comment: I added text. Expected output was below the sample.

Comment: Sorry, can you check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) ?

Comment: I have tried to add clarification.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I appreciate being downvoted without given reasons why my question deserves a downvote. I was able to figure it out on my own though. Hopefully, this may answer other people's questions in the future.

```
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    temp = []  #initialize array
    with open('C:/Users/sword/Anaconda3/envs/exceltest/RF_SubjP02_Free_STATIC_TR01.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
         csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
         for row in csvreader:
             if csvreader.line_num == 3:  
                temp.append(row)     #gets column names and saves to array  
             if csvreader.line_num >= 6:
                if row: 
                     temp.append(row)  # gets data values and saves to array
                else: #stops at blank row
                     break
    df = pd.DataFrame(temp) #creates a dataframe from an array
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]  #make top row the column names
    df.reindex(df.index.drop(1))
    print(df)
```